# Convergence in upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the upper half-plane $\mathbb H^{+}$ & let $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb H^{+}$ . If $lim _{t \to \infty} f(it) = 0$ ; prove that:  $lim _{t \to \infty} f(tz) = 0$ ,$\forall z \in \mathbb H^{+}$ .

My thought: Following the hint "to use Montel's Theorem" , I was thinking of considering the family : $f_{t}(z) = f(tz)$ ; but could NOT come up with a complete proof. Please help me out.

Comment: That's very good so far. So you know that $\mathscr{F} = \{ f_t : t > 0\}$ is a normal family. Now, what does it mean that $\mathscr{F}$ is a normal family?

Comment: there exists a subsequence which converges normally on every compact subset of $\mathbb H^{+}$ . But then??

Comment: "Every sequence in $\mathscr{F}$ has a subsequence ...". A short argument shows that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(tz)$ exists for every $z\in\mathbb{H}^+$. Now you need to see that that limit can only be $0$.

Comment: I mean exactly here I am stucked at... not only in this one but a few problems on Montel's theorem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded, the family

$$\mathscr{F} = \{ f_t : 0 < t\}$$

is a (globally, hence a fortiori locally) bounded family, and by Montel's theorem it is normal.

Pick a sequence $t_n \to \infty$. By the normality of $\mathscr{F}$, we may assume [tacitly passing to a subsequence] that the sequence $f_{t_n}$ converges locally uniformly to the holomorphic function $g \colon \mathbb{H}^+ \to \mathbb{C}$.

Use $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(ti) = 0$ to deduce $g\equiv 0$ (identity theorem). Conclude that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(tz) = 0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Okkay.... Now I got it... Thank you.. Daniel Fischer..